# Not losing the quality of pictures saved with cv2.imwrite()

Tags: python, opencv, colors, python-2.x

I am wondering seriously about the effects of `cv2.imwrite()` function of OpenCV.

I noticed that when I read pictures with `cv2.imread()` and save them again with `cv2.imwrite()` function, their quality is not the same any more for the human eyes.

I ask you how can I keep the quality of the image the same as the original after saving it using `cv2.imwrite()` function.

I ask this question because I have really a serious issue in a larger program and when I checked the quality of the pictures saved by this function, I guesses that my problem comes certainly from this function.

For example, I draw using the mouse movements small  red (Red=255) squares on picture . When I save the picture and count the number of pixels that have Red color equal to 255 I get very few of them only even if I draw a lot of them in pure red color. But when I check the image by my eyes, I notice the red pixels I drawed are not correctly saved in the correct red color I chosed (255).

Any one does know how to resolve this problem ? I mean to save the pictures using OpenCV without degrading its quality.

Comment: which format do you write? jpg? gif?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JPEG is a lossy format, you need to save your images as PNG as it is a lossless format.

Comment: Every time someone complains about why the quality of their image is terrible when saving to file, from what I have seen in answering questions, this is the reason why. +1.

Comment: tried converting the jpegs to pngs, but it still suffered a major color loss, as if a layers added over it removing all the brightness. Here are 2 for comparison if anyone's interested.
https://storage.googleapis.com/p_temp/1491389137.74.5713443883363%281%29.jpg
And 
https://storage.googleapis.com/p_temp/1.png