# Color in image gets dull after saving it in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am using opencv module to read and write the image. here is the code and below is the image i am reading and second image is after saving it on disk using `cv2.imwrite()`.

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('originalImage.jpg')
cv2.imwrite('test.jpg',img)
```

[image: original image]

[image: image saved using opencv]

It is significantly visible that colors are dull in second image. Is there any workaround to this problem or I am missing on some sort of setting parameters..?

Comment: Try saving in another image format

Comment: @RickM. can you suggest the format..? should i try PNG..?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not losing the quality of pictures saved with cv2.imwrite()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28940711/not-losing-the-quality-of-pictures-saved-with-cv2-imwrite)

Comment: With png also I am facing the same quality degradation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have done a bit of research on the point @mark raised about ICC profile. I have figured out a way to handle this in python PIL module. here is the code that worked for me. I have also learned to use PNG file format rather JPEG to do lossless conversion.

```
import Image
img = Image.open('originalImage.jpg')
img.save('test.jpg',icc_profile=img.info.get('icc_profile'))
```

I hope this will help others as well.

Comment: Well done - and thank you for sharing your findings back with the community.

Comment: Thanks @Mark it was because of your finding I was able to solve my problem.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that the initial image (on the left in the diagram) has an attached ICC profile whereas the second one (on the right) does not.

[image]

I obtained the above image by running the **ImageMagick** utility called `identify` like this:

```
identify -verbose first.jpg    > 1.txt
identify -verbose second.jpg   > 2.txt
```

Then I ran the brilliant `opendiff` tool (which is part of **macOS**) like this:

```
opendiff [12].txt
```

You can extract the ICC profile from the first image also with **ImageMagick** like this:

```
convert first.jpg profile.icc
```

Comment: So how do i take care of this ICC profile while writing the image through opencv..?

Comment: Nice catch! However this does not solve OPs problem!

Comment: Hi @AnderBiguri Yes, I agree it doesn't to *solve* the problem but I believe that answers that help understand what the problem is are perfectly acceptable and if two folks each know half an answer... well, we may be able to work out a full answer between us. For the moment, I am going to say that I believe **OpenCV** is more biased towards solving "computer vision problems" and is less skewed towards worrying about the fidelity of colour management for print and reproduction purposes so I suspect OP will need to take account of the ICC profile himself. I may be wrong :-)

Comment: @RikenMehta OpenCV doesn't read or write ICC profiles (or other metadata) so you'll need to look outside of OpenCV for your solution.

Comment: @SSteve i have to make a montage of images and write it back to disk for later use of visuals. So can you suggest me some other modules in python that i can use..?

Comment: @RikenMehta Sorry. I know OpenCV but not Python image management modules.

Comment: @RikenMehta You can try using the PIL (python imaging library) module.

Answer (score 0):

Your first input image has some icc-Profile associated in the meta-data, which is an optional attribute and most devices may not inject it in the first place. The ICC profile basically performs a sort of color correction, and the correction coefficients are calculated for each unique device during calibration.

Modern Web Browsers, Image Viewing utilities mainly take into account this ICC profile information before rendering the image onto the screen, that is the reason why there is a diff in both the images.

But Unfortunately OpenCV doesn't reads the ICC config from the meta data of the image to perform any color correction.

Comment: do you have idea about any utility that takes care of ICC profile..? In any language and in any framework.?

Comment: I Don't guess if there is any library that supports reading image with meta data, but you may look at this [link](https://imageoptim.com/color-profiles.html) to get images in sRGB profile rather than ICC.